# Should I make one Map object and reference it all over the place or instantiate each time I need it?

Tags: java

I have a JavaFX controller that calls a method from many different methods within the class.

```
sendToNode(String name, Map<String, Object> p){}
```

right now in each method I will create a new map and fill it with parameters.

```
public void someMethod(){
    Map<String, Object> p = new HashMap();
    p.put("a", 777);
    sendToNode("slave", p);
}
```

Is it better (memory and efficiency wise) to create a class variable and just clear it each time instead of instantiating a new one in every method?

```
public MyClass{
    Map<String, Object> p = new HashMap();

    public void someMethod(){
        p.clear();
        p.put("a", 777);
        sendToNode("slave", p);
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the data ever change, or is it fixed for the lifetime of your application?

Comment: The difference in resources should be small. The thread and other vunerabilities you introduce should keep you where you are now.

Comment: The data changes. each method sends a different set of parameters.

Comment: @Mad Physicist what vulnerabilities?

Comment: @DanielH. Vunerabilities may have been the wrong word. Concurrency issues sounds much better.

Comment: @Mad Physicist It seems you are saying I am doing something wrong but I am not sure what it is exactly. Am I doing something the wrong way here? Still learning :-)

Comment: @DanielH. You are not doing something wrong. I don't have a full answer, so I was just trying to point out a consideration about shared variables in a multithreaded environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating each time is inherently better; the performance hit is so minimal that you honestly shouldn't care (you probably have better places to optimize).

Moreover, by making a single class variable and clearing it out like that, you're going to introduce concurrency issues you'll just have to solve later that will be much more complicated and likely remove any performance gains you see.

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Makes sense! and thanks for the optimization quote. I think I spend too long wondering what is the best way to do something instead of just writing the code and optimizing later.

Comment: One thing that could prove more helpful in future is to avoid passing maps, and actually pass objects which are more strongly defined - that way you give the JVM a better chance to optimize for you under the hood.

Comment: Well, I am using the Map to build a JSON to be sent across an intranet. does it make sense in that context?

Comment: Yes, although you might want to check out [Jackson](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson); it allows you to serialize your Java objects directly to JSON. It typically makes working with JSON easier, but it might be too a steep learning curve for now.